# How did I mount my Windows partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, mount, automount

So, 2 months ago, I wanted to access my Windows partitions while my device is booted on Ubuntu. I had some other work, so I gave this work to my friend. He tried some things apparently. It shows the drives from Windows on the left hand pane of Nautilus. But it didn't work. Clicking on it used to give some sort of mounting error.

Now, I happened to have a lot of free time and I began studying the forums and web pages. You know, about editing the `fstab` file, about the mounting positions, (`/mnt` and `/media`), about file systems (ntfs and ntfs-3g) and some other stuff.

Just when I was ready to do the fstab editing, I launched nautilus, and casually clicked my windows drive and all of a sudden, they started getting mounted on `/media`. Just by clicking on the partition name on left hand pane. My question is.. HOW?

I checked the fstab file, there are no lines added for mounting ntfs file systems. I checked the startup applications also, just in case. But no command for mounting there too. I don't remember installing any kind of tools to help me on this. Sadly, my friend doesn't remember what he did back then. To check if this is a temporary mount during this session, I even restarted the system. But it works this time too. How is this happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Answer (score 0):

On my system it makes a difference if Windows has been ended by shutdown or by reboot. If Windows has been ended by reboot I can mount the Windows partition in Ubuntu. When Windows will be ended by shutdown obviously it lets the filesystem in a state which cannot be accessed by Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You mean to say, as long as windows is ended by reboot, I can mount them on ubuntu with no commands?

Comment: Reboot or full shutdown. Windows has this tendency since 8 to put system into hibernation, so unless you disable fastboot , you wont mount it. And also just generally avoid hibernation